# Update .Paragraphs.Count variable after increasing new paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a code which I want to loop through the entire document, check whether it starts with a number, if yes, add a Paragraph.

However, it doesn't count the new paragraphs in the loop, so it doesn't execute until the end of the document.

```
Sub test()

lastpar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

For i = 1 To lastpar

If IsNumeric(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Words(1).Characters(1)) = True Then
If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i + 1).Range.Characters.Count > 1 Then
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Paragraphs.Add
lastpar = lastpar + 1
End If
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

As you can see, I tried adding `lastpar = lastpar + 1` to the code, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it work by adding `While i < lastpar`:

```
Sub test()

lastpar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

While i < lastpar

For i = 1 To lastpar

If IsNumeric(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Words(1).Characters(1)) = True Then
If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i + 1).Range.Characters.Count > 1 Then
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Paragraphs.Add
lastpar = lastpar + 1
End If
End If

Next i

Wend

End Sub
```